# Python3 Argparse metavar brackets parsed weirdly

Tags: python-3.x, formatting, argparse, brackets

I am using argparse in python3, and I get some strange things:

A short version of code that I'm using is:

```
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='add/remove items')
argparser.add_argument('-a', action='append',     metavar="Item(s)", help='add one or more items to the list')
argparser.add_argument('-r', action='append',     metavar="Item(s)", help='remove one or more items from the list')
args = argparser.parse_args()
```

When I run the script with the -h flag, I get this output:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-a Items)] [-r Item(s]

add/remove items

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -a CPE(s)   add one or more items to the list
  -r CPE(s)   remove one or more items from the list
```

Mind the weird parsing of the brackets in the first line.

What causes this, and how do I solve this?

Comment: Seems to be a known bug : http://bugs.python.org/issue11874 : "It doesn't seem to be the exact same problem, but still this very simple example with parentheses in metavar fails to format correctly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to have the possibility of having multiple items. Another way to do this with argparse is as follows:

```
import argparse
argparser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='add/remove items')
argparser.add_argument('-a', metavar="item", nargs="*", help='add one or more items to the list')
argparser.add_argument('-r', metavar="item", nargs="*", help='remove one or more items from the list')
args = argparser.parse_args()
```

The key point is the use of `nargs="*"` (0 or more arguments). The help becomes:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-a [item [item ...]]] [-r [item [item ...]]]
```

This way, you do not have to use "`Item(s)`", and you also follow a standard practice.

**PS**: I see what you wanted to do. With `action="append"`, you are actually allowing the user to specify multiple `-a` and `-r` options. In this case, you should definitely write `"Item"` (and not "`Item(s)`"), since each option takes a single item. This solves your problem too (your help message should indicate that multiple `-a` and `-r` options can be given).

Comment: Maybe changing my program to the first option would be better in my case. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: The OP is using the `append` action type in the intended way.  `nargs='*'` accomplishes the same thing.  The choice depends on what is clearer to your end users.  `*` can be used with `append`, producing a nested list of lists.

Answer (score 3):

It's the `()` in your metavars that is causing the mangled usage.  The usage formatter uses `()` to mark require mutually exclusive groups, and then removes surplus ones.  So it tries to keep `( -o | -t)`, but change `(-o)` to `-o`.  Unfortunately that code does not distinguish between the ones it added and the ones you added via the metavar (or help line).

Your line was formatted as:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-a Item(s)] [-r Item(s)]
```

but it removed the outer pair of `()` which I have replaced with *:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-a Item*s)] [-r Item(s*]
```

http://bugs.python.org/issue11874 focuses on a different usage problem, one which occurs when the usage line is long and needs to be split.  But the last 2 posts in that issue deal with this issue.

If you don't like the limitations of the automatic `usage` formatting, you can give the `parser` your own custom `usage` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

My solution in Python 2.7 was to override argparse.format_usage() and argparse.format_help().  You encode your metavars and then decode them after argparse does its formatting:

```
FIXES = (('\[', '%lb'), ('\]', '%rb'), ('\(', '%lp'), ('\)', '%rp'))
def encode_parens(text):
    for orig, encoded in FIXES:
        text = re.sub(orig, encoded, text)
    return text
def decode_parens(text):
    for orig, encoded in FIXES:
        text = re.sub(encoded, orig[1:], text)
    return text

class MyArgParser(argparse.ArgumentParser):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyArgParser, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def format_usage(self, *args, **kwargs):
        u = super(MyArgParser, self).format_usage(*args, **kwargs)
        return decode_parens(u)
    def format_help(self, *args, **kwargs):
        h = super(MyArgParser, self).format_help(*args, **kwargs)
        return decode_parens(h)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    argparser = MyArgParser(description='add/remove items')
    argparser.add_argument('-a', action='append', metavar=encode_parens("Item(s)"), help='add one or more items to the list')
    argparser.add_argument('-r', action='append', metavar=encode_parens("Item(s)"), help='remove one or more items from the list')
    args = argparser.parse_args()
```

That yields what you want:

```
usage: arg.py [-h] [-a Item(s)] [-r Item(s)]
```

It also fixes square brackets, which argparse doesn't like either.