# Issue with automatic usage string from argparse with nargs='*' and metavar with optional plural "(s)"

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing a program that uses a positional argument that takes in "the rest" of the arguments, like this

```
import argparse

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'filenames',
        nargs='*',
        metavar="filename(s)",
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

Here I have used the `metavar` parameter to get a nicer help text. But the issue is the `usage` string:

```
>python test_argparse_plural.py -h
usage: test_argparse_plural.py [-h] [filenames) [filename(s ...]]

positional arguments:
  filename(s)

optional arguments:
  -h, --help   show this help message and exit
```

It seems like it doesn't handle the `(s)` part very well. I would instead like the `usage` string to be either

```
test_argparse_plural.py [-h] [filename(s)]
```

or perhaps

```
test_argparse_plural.py [-h] [filename1, filename2, ...]
```

(or anything else sensible, really)

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python3 Argparse metavar brackets parsed weirdly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28234992/python3-argparse-metavar-brackets-parsed-weirdly)

Comment: And a bug/issue currently under consideration: https://bugs.python.org/issue38438  - argparse "usage" overly-complex with nargs="*".  Don't try to be too cleaver with the `metavar`.  The `usage` formater isn't very robust.

Comment: If I'm reading the argparse source correctly, things go wrong when [argparse tries to clean up separators for mutually exclusive groups](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.0/Lib/argparse.py#L480), because the code assumes any parentheses and brackets come from argparse code.

Comment: One option is to provide you own custom `usage` parameter (when starting the parser).  Writing that one line of text will be faster than tracking down the issue(s) the code, or even asking us this question! Also https://bugs.python.org/issue18349

Comment: The program in question and it's arguments is under active development, so I prefer to keep the automatic `usage` formatter. So I'll just skip the `(s)` for now and check back with the issues you've linked to in a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  This is what I came up with:

```
import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        'filenames',
        nargs='+',
        metavar='filename',
        help='file(s) to process'
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

This will produce the following usage:

```
nargs_plus_demo.py -h
usage: nargs_plus_demo.py [-h] filename [filename ...]

positional arguments:
  filename    file(s) to process

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: "Change `nargs='*'` to `nargs='+'`" is not an answer to OP's question.