# Generating better help from argparse when nargs='*'

Tags: python, argparse

Like many command line tools, mine accepts optional filenames.  Argparse seems to support this via `nargs='*'`, which is working for me as expected:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
        'files',
        help='file(s) to parse instead of stdin',
        nargs='*')

parser.parse_args()
```

However, the help output is bizarre:

```
$ ./help.py -h
usage: help.py [-h] [files [files ...]]
```

How can I avoid the nested optional and repeated parameter name?  The repetition adds no information beyond [files ...], which is the traditional way optional parameter lists are indicated on Unix:

```
$ grep --help
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
        [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
        [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
        [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

$ ls --help
Usage:
  exa [options] [files...]

$ vim --help
Usage:
  nvim [options] [file ...]      Edit file(s)
```

Any help is appreciated.  I'm trying argparse because using it seems to be a Python best practice, but this help output is a dealbreaker for me.

Comment: Looking at the docs, there's an example where this is formatted as you expect https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.MetavarTypeHelpFormatter (the third example) so this might very well be a bug.

Comment: @Boris Thanks.  I see it, but running the sample code no longer produces the documented result.

Comment: @JeffSchwab turns out it's not "no longer produces" but "your python version doesn't yet produce". This was changed to work the way you expect in Python 3.9, which came out October 5th, 2020.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!  Confirmed using python:3.9 from DockerHub.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58797637/issue-with-automatic-usage-string-from-argparse-with-nargs-and-metavar-with

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was fixed in Python 3.9, see https://bugs.python.org/issue38438 and [commit `a0ed99bc`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/a0ed99bca8475cbc82e9202aa354faba2a4620f4) that fixed it.

Your code produces the usage message you expect if run on 3.9:

```py
Python 3.9.0 (default, Oct 12 2020, 02:44:01) 
[GCC 9.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('files', help='file(s) to parse instead of stdin', nargs='*')
_StoreAction(option_strings=[], dest='files', nargs='*', const=None, default=None, type=None, choices=None, help='file(s) to parse instead of stdin', metavar=None)
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [-h] [files ...]
```

Answer (score 1):

**For all versions prior to Python 3.9:**

You may override the usage line by passing a `usage="%(prog)s [options]"` string [when instantiating ArgumentParser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#usage) or by updating the `usage` property of the existing instance.

You can combine this with [`ArgumentParser.format_usage()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#printing-help) if you want to to let it generate a usage string, but use regex or string replacement to replace only `nargs` options.

For example:

```
import argparse
import re

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    'files',
    help='file(s) to parse instead of stdin',
    nargs='*',
)

usage = parser.format_usage()[7:]  # remove "usage: " prefix
parser.usage = re.sub(r'\[(.+?) \[\1 ...\]\]', r'[\1 ...]', usage)

parser.parse_args()
```

Produces:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [files ...]

positional arguments:
  files       file(s) to parse instead of stdin

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely better than nothing.  I don’t really want to maintain the usage line myself though; I want argparse to do the right thing.  Tbh, this seems like a bug, and I'm surprised not to find any existing discussion about it.

Comment: @JeffSchwab I have updated the answer to include an example on how to let argparse handle the usage string for you while only overriding this behavior.